# Visual Defect on Privileges Page

Tags: bug, user-interface, css

On the [privileges page](https://superuser.com/help/privileges), when hovering over a row, the `text-decoration:underline` rule looks weird.  Most of the the content is inside of a div inside of an anchor tag, so most of it doesn't have underlines, but some will pop up before the text `_likethis`.

Here's an example from Super User and from Stack Overflow:

[**Super User**](https://superuser.com/help/privileges):

[image: Screenshot - Super]
[image: CSS - Super]

[**Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges):

[image: Screenshot - Stack]
[image: CSS - Stack]

[**Repro'd on:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X362Z.png)

- Win 7 - Chrome 44
- Win 7 - IE 11
- Win 7 - FF 39
- Win 7 - Safari 5.1.7
- Android 5.0.1 - Chrome 44

Comment: I can't repro this (Firefox 40 on WIndows).

Comment: What OS and browser are you using?

Comment: @DavidPostill, updated.  I'm not sure why it's not happening for you, but I think it's safe to say it's cross browser/device.

Comment: It does as the OP suggests for me on Win7 64-bit with IE11. Weird. :)

Comment: Same happens for me on Win10 64-bit with Firefox 40.0.2

Comment: Happens to me on Win7 64-bit with Firefox 40.0.3

Comment: I subconsciously noticed this. Like once I read your post I realized I've been ignoring it this whole time. (Windows 10 Pro / Chrome 45)